# Kafka-streams: setting internal topics cleanup policy to delete doesn't work

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use kafka streams reduce function and it creates some state store change log kafka internal topic ( like app-KSTREAM-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000002-changelog ).

I wanted to set **retention bytes** and change **cleanup policy** to **delete** to prevent the storage being full. So I set following configs in kafka streams code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(StreamsConfig.TOPIC_PREFIX + TopicConfig.RETENTION_BYTES_CONFIG, Constants.INTERNAL_TOPICS_RETENTION_BYTES);
props.put(StreamsConfig.TOPIC_PREFIX + TopicConfig.CLEANUP_POLICY_CONFIG, TopicConfig.CLEANUP_POLICY_DELETE);
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
```

However, when a new topic is generated, **only** the retention config is applied to the newly generated internal topic and cleanup policy remains **compact**.

Is there any missing step to do so ?  ( or Isn't it possible to set internal topics cleanup policy to delete ?)

I use kafka version **1.0.0** and kafka-streams version **1.0.0**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks Guozhang for his answer in [kafka mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201809.mbox/%3CCAHwHRrVpG2Ne-%3DBjuHWWWFa8MGJ5MxVwYVuo40UPXktGcwxyqQ%40mail.gmail.com%3E):

> The issue you described seems like an old bug that is resolved since 1.1.0
>   (as part of the fix in https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6150).
>
> ... You do not need to upgrade broker in order to use newer Streams library
>   versions.

Upgrading kafka-streams version to **1.1.0** fixed the issue.

Comment: "to prevent the storage being full" -- not sure what you mean by this. If the topic is compacted, the storage will be proportional to the number of unique keys. If you have an infinite number of unique keys, your local store will still grow unbounded. Your usage pattern indicates an anti-pattern---are you sure you use Kafka Streams correctly? There is no TTL for RocksDB stores. A current workaround is to use a windowed-store to expire older data.